# Is there a "lhs" and "rhs" function in Mathematica that is similar to Maple?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, maple

In Maple, we can use "lhs" and "rhs" functions to retrieve the left or right hand side of an equation, but I can find a similar one in Mathematica. Could anyone suggest how to do this in Mathematica?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you are getting no answers this is usually due to the fact that you have not asked in a very clear and detailed way. Please add more information then you will have a better impact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if you can adapt this.

I name an equation `e1` in this way

```
e1 = x==y
```

Then the lhs of e1 is

```
e1[[1]]
```

which returns

```
x
```

and the rhs of e1 is

```
e1[[2]]
```

which returns

```
y
```

Comment: And what about vector, for example ${{a==b},{b==c}}$ ?

Comment: @dtn if those equalities have not simplified to just `True` or `False` and you just want `a` from that then `{{a==b},{c==d}}[[1,1,1]]` gives you `a`. If you want a list of all the left hand sides then `Map[#[[1,1]]&,{{a==b},{c==d}}]` will give you a list `{a,c}` and if neither of those are what you really want then please provide a more specific example.